# How do I capture and save live feed of Flash video?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, video

Is there a tool, any type of programming library,  or a way to capture live feed of Flash video and save it? I don't want to capture the screen but rather like to capture the actual feed.

Comment: I'm untagging this as PHP because this is not possible to do via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly in Flash. Instead you must use a Flash Server. The open source one is Red 5.

Check it out: http://osflash.org/red5